# How to exclude CSS from one Page? Or how to reset margins of one page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, margin

I come to you with a seemingly quick fix, but nothing I've tried has worked the way I've planned it.

So what I'd like to do is apply the following CSS below to all my site's pages, EXCEPT for one: .page-id-145. I've tried using section:not(.page-id-145) attached at the start of the following code, but it ends up messing up my other pages, while fixing the page I need. How can I simply JUST exclude the following code from the page I want, without messing up the other pages? I specifically want the (margin and float) to go away on page id 145.

Essentially, I just need a way to set the margin/float for this specific page: http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/great-albums-rym-list/ to the left, and not in the middle, which is what the following CSS describes.

Here is my theme CSS that may influence the specific page in question:

```
#header,
#main-content,
#wrapper-footer {
  float: none;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;        
}
#wrapper #main-content {      /* this section likely must change */
  padding: 28px 28px 10px;
  width: 720px;         
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
#content {
  float: none;
  width: 750px;       
}
```

And here is one other line of an exception I made previously, that may or may not influence it:

```
.page-id-145 .header-image {display: none;}
```

In summary, I simply want to start my margin on a specific page to the LEFT side, instead of what has been specified in the above CSS. Unfortunately, I have gone through a variety of iterations to make it work like :not and even unset, inherit, and initial, but to no avail. Another detail that may work includes the fact that this specific Wordpress theme was designed to include sidebar widgets - not sure if that will help. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance, and have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, change the theme's css to this:

```
#wrapper #main-content {
   padding: 28px 28px 10px;
   width: 720px;
}

#wrapper:not(.page-id-145) #main-content {
   margin: 0 auto;
   float: none;
}
```

Since the page-id-145 class is applied to the same element that has the wrapper id, you have to specify the :not(.page-id-145) on that element. I split out the styles into two sections, the first section will be applied to all instances of #wrapper #main-content, while the second section won't be applied to page-id-145.

If you can't change the theme's css (and can only add custom css) then you can use this to override it:

```
#wrapper.page-id-145 #main-content {
   margin: 0; /* can also be unset or initial, whatever you prefer */
   float: /* whatever you want it to be here */;
}
```

Comment: The first choice worked to perfection, thank you so much. I tried this same idea earlier, but I put the :not in front of #wrapper like a n00b, so I guess that's the difference. Thank you so much for your help! Cheers.

Comment: Hooray! No problem :)